# Where do I put kann in this sentence?

Tags: modal-verb

I'm not sure about the place of *kann* in the sentence:

"Ich kann auch nicht so gut Deutsch sprechen, aber mein Freund Uno wirklich sehr gut **kann**"

Is it before wirklich or at the end and why. Since können is a modalverben, I wonder about its behavior when it's the only verb used (like in the second part of the sentence)

Comment: The second »kann« can be omitted: »Ich kann auch nicht so gut Deutsch sprechen, mein Freund Uno dagegen [wirklich] _sehr_ gut.«

Comment: It doesn't matter if the verb is a modal adverb or not. What matters is if it's conjugated or not, and if it is in a main clause, or subclause. "Aber" is a main clause conjunction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct grammar here is:

"..., aber mein Freund Uno kann es wirklich sehr gut."

or

"..., aber mein Freund Uno kann wirklich sehr gut Deutsch sprechen."

The *es* references *Deutsch sprechen* from the first part and is required. The second example is grammatically correct but it sounds a bit awkward because a phrase from the first part is duplicated.

Comment: "..., aber mein Freund Uno schon." would be a more natural variant to avoid the repetition.